# Yarn and wasm module linking does not work due to yarn caching

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, webassembly, wasm-pack

I have a very simple app here where index.html simply imports index.js where:

index.js

```
import * as wasm from "wasm";
wasm.greet();
```

lib.rs

```
mod utils;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
#[cfg(feature = "wee_alloc")]
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern { fn alert(s: &str); }

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn greet() { alert("Wasm is running haha!"); }
```

package.json

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "wasm": "portal:../pkg"
  },
...
```

Now, here is my issue:

- When I use `"file:../pkg"` in package.json, everything works, but if
  I make a change and recompile using wasm-pack it does not update.
  Even running `yarn install` will not update. The only way I can get
  changes to show is by running `yarn install --check-files` but then
  the install takes time and it's quite painful.
- When I use `"portal:../pkg"` in package.json instead, I get an error `ERROR in ./index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve "wasm" ....`. This is not what I expect.
- When I use `"link:../pkg"` everything works as planned, and I do not have to run `yarn install` every-time I compile to see the changes. This is great and what I really want.

Yet, when I read protocols here https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols the difference between link and portal is only that portal will follow dependencies if `package.json` exists in my `../pkg` folder. In my case, it does, and I expect to have further dependencies there. So how can I get portal to work? And why is it not working now when link is working?